# get image as an byte from client such as Android and convert it to Image

Tags: php, android

i'm write simple application to save users avatar and images. in Android client i must be convert image into Bitmap and then convert that to Byte. for example:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
img.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
img.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();

ByteArrayOutputStream s = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, s);
byte[] byteArray = s.toByteArray();
```

after send `byteArray` to server how to convert it to Image to save it into server? my web service is writen with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the received bytes to an image as they are already an image. In fact the bytes represent a PNG image. If you would just save them to file you would end up with a PNG file.